Intellisense feature in salesforce apex (execute anonymous window)
I am tring to call math.mod function but it is not invoking, can anyone please help here, I am using free developer org. 

Autocompletion in Salesforce Developer console is retired. It is recommended to use tools like Salesforce extensions with VSCode or Code Builder
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_dev_console_fullapex_sunset.htm&language=en_US&release=246&type=5

Thanks Mohith..!
